# .net : How to add a user to a Active Directory Security Group using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, active-directory, ldap

I am finding a reference to a security group to which I need to add user by using the following code:

```
string strActiveDirectoryPath = @"GC://domain.com";

DirectoryEntry directoryEntryRoot = new DirectoryEntry(strActiveDirectoryPath);

using (DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(directoryEntryRoot))
{  
    searcher.PageSize = 1000;
    searcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=group)(cn=*SGNAME*))";
    //searcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
    SearchResult securityGroup = searcher.FindOne();  
}
```

The above code sometimes throws an exception saying

> Search resulted in too many records

Is my logic of fetching the security group correct?

Then I get reference to the user and try to add it to the security group:

```
searcher.Filter = "(SAMAccountName=" + UserAlias + ")";
searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("givenname");
searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("displayName");               

SearchResult userALias = searcher.FindOne();

DirectoryEntry ent = new DirectoryEntry(securityGroup.Path);              
string domainString = "GC://domain.com/";
int Start =  domainString.Length;
string member = userALias.Path.Substring(domainString.Length);

ent.Properties["member"].Add(member);
// ent.Invoke("Add", new object[] { s });

ent.CommitChanges();
ent.Close();
```

I have created an instance of `DirectoryEntry` and provided a path of the security group that I have found.

What should be provided to `DirectoryEntry`?

`CommitChanges` fails with exception:

> The server is unwilling to process the request.

[image]

Comment: Are you using .NET Core or not?

Comment: @GabrielLuci I want to use .net core but i am not whether .net core supports Directory Search Library or not

Comment: It does, but only if you install the `Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility` NuGet package, which only works on Windows. (you won't be able to run your app on any other OS anymore)

Comment: I only ask because you tagged both `.net` and `.net-core`, but the `.net` tag is only for non-core questions.

Comment: ok. now i am facing error operation not allowed through GC port

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a couple issue. First:

```
searcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=group)(cn=*SGNAME*))";
SearchResult securityGroup = searcher.FindOne();
```

Because you're using wildcards, you're searching for any group with `SGNAME` anywhere in the name. This has two problems:

1. Even though the [`cn` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-cn) is indexed, the index can't be used because you're using a wildcard at the beginning. It has to look at *every* group to try and find matches. This will slow down your search.
2. Because you're doing a wildcard search, it could match to more than one account. The [documentation for `DirectorySearcher.FindOne()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.findone) says:

> If more than one entry is found during the search, only the first entry is returned.

So you can't guarantee that the group returned is actually the one you want.

Why are you getting an exception then? I don't know. I would be curious to see the full exception details. There will probably be a hex number in there.

But I don't think that really matters. All of this would be solved by just matching the name exactly:

```
searcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=group)(cn=SGNAME))";
```

**Adding a member to the group**

My guess is that your `member` variable isn't a proper `distinguishedName`. Instead of trying to parse the DN out of the `Path`, just ask for the `distinguishedName` in the search results. For example:

```
searcher.Filter = "(SAMAccountName=" + UserAlias + ")";
searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedName");

SearchResult userALias = searcher.FindOne();

DirectoryEntry ent = securityGroup.GetDirectoryEntry();              

string member = (string) userALias.Properties["distinguishedName"][0];

ent.Properties["member"].Add(member);

ent.CommitChanges();
ent.Close();
```

**Update:** You also cannot update via the Global Catalog. You must use `LDAP://`:

```
string strActiveDirectoryPath = "LDAP://domain.com";
```

Or, if you really do need to search the GC (if you have multiple domains in your forest) then you'll have to switch to LDAP when you create your `DirectoryEntry` for the group.

```
DirectoryEntry ent = new DirectoryEntry(securityGroup.Path.Replace("GC://", "LDAP://"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The suggestion that you have given is worked while finding security group. However now i am getting exception. Updated Question with exception

Comment: The `ExtendedErrorMessage` says the real problem. I've updated my answer. You just need to use `LDAP://` instead of `GC://`

Comment: Or I added another option if you do really need to perform the search on the GC.

Comment: Yes that replace logic is required. But i am now getting error : Access is denied. Not sure how to check account permissions. Thanks for your help. Appreciate it

Comment: If you are not passing credentials to `DirectoryEntry` for the group, then it will use whatever credentials the application is being run with. So either you need to run the app with an account that has permissions to modify the group, or pass credentials to `DirectoryEntry` for an account that has permissions.

Comment: Can you brief me about GC and LDAP ? I know there is a lot of stuff online but it is kind of confusing

Comment: Regular LDAP connects to a domain controller on port 389 and only contains data from the one domain of the DC. Most DCs also act as Global Catalogs (but not necessarily so), which still uses the LDAP protocol, but on port 3268 and contains data from all of the domains in the forest. Because it can serve data on other domains, it is not writeable (because the server giving you the information may not be able to write it). Also, not all attributes are replicated to the GC.

Comment: Now things are cleat to me :) Thanks Gabriel . Have a good one

Comment: Adding a member  from code is disabled by Microsoft as 
 of now check link :https://microsoft.sharepoint.com/sites/itweb/Identity/idweb/faq/Pages/FIM-PA-Retirement.aspx

Comment: That page requires login and doesn't let me see it. What does it say?

Comment: FIM programmatic access is used for automation of Group Management specific to unique business requirements and process controls.DSRE Identity and Access Management will no longer be onboarding new requests for this service. Service will be replaced by the CoreIdentity platform.The CoreIdentity platform will be the future service for managing Groups.
The timeline for implementation and release of the Core Identity platform is estimated to be in Q4.  In the meantime, the Bulk Operations feature within the IDWeb portal will be the single point for management of large group updates and changes.

Comment: That's the website you're trying to grant access to?

Comment: its not a website. Idweb is a portal where you can add users to a group and when i raised a ticket for them saying i am not able to add user using code to SG, They replied back saying service is retired as of now,